# Merge two or more object arrays based on shared id

Tags: php, arrays, object, merging-data

I am trying to merge two or more multidimensional array based on same ID.

All the arrays are populated from different database table queries.

My Goal: Trying to merge all the arrays together and fetch the data to view page table.

I'm using codeigniter frame work for my project.

`$array1` is from the 'members' table.
`$array2`, `$array3` and `$array4` are from the 'registration' table with a where condition.

My arrays:

```
$array1 = [
    1 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 1,
        "m_name_e" => "Titus C.",
        "member_id" => "KZI37M3025",
        "gender" => "Male",
        "m_number" => 9489455057,
        "familyid" => "KZI54F2256"
    ],
    2 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 2,
        "m_name_e" => "Baby Helen",
        "member_id" => "KZI45M6402",
        "gender" => "Female",
        "m_number" => null,
        "familyid" => "KZI54F2256"
    ],
    3 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 3,
        "m_name_e" => "Satheesh Premananth T.",
        "member_id" => "KZI69M3438",
        "gender" => "Male",
        "m_number" => null,
        "familyid" => "KZI69F5619"
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    1 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 1,
        "do_birth" => "1937-09-18"
    ],
    2 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 2,
        "do_birth" => "1945-02-06"
    ],
    3 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 3,
        "do_birth" => "1968-04-12"
    ]
];

$array3 = [
    3 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 3,
        "do_baptism" => "1969-04-13"
    ]
];

$array4 = [
    1 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 1,
        "do_confirm" => "1954-04-07"
    ],
    3 => (object) [
        "mem_tbl_id" => 3,
        "do_confirm" => "1990-04-29"
    ]
];
```

Desired result:

```
array (
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'mem_tbl_id' => 1,
     'm_name_e' => 'Titus C.',
     'member_id' => 'KZI37M3025',
     'gender' => 'Male',
     'm_number' => 9489455057,
     'familyid' => 'KZI54F2256',
     'do_birth' => '1937-09-18',
     'do_confirm' => '1954-04-07',
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'mem_tbl_id' => 2,
     'm_name_e' => 'Baby Helen',
     'member_id' => 'KZI45M6402',
     'gender' => 'Female',
     'm_number' => null,
     'familyid' => 'KZI54F2256',
     'do_birth' => '1945-02-06',
  ),
  3 => 
  (object) array(
     'mem_tbl_id' => 3,
     'm_name_e' => 'Satheesh Premananth T.',
     'member_id' => 'KZI69M3438',
     'gender' => 'Male',
     'm_number' => null,
     'familyid' => 'KZI69F5619',
     'do_birth' => '1968-04-12',
     'do_baptism' => '1969-04-13',
     'do_confirm' => '1990-04-29',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Will using MySQL JOIN solve your problem? https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-join

Comment: This task is best left to SQL as Harish has said.  We cannot give proper guidance because we don't have enough details about your database schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **array_merge_recursive**();

```
$marger_array = array_merge_recursive($Array1, $Array2, $Array3, $Array4);

var_dump($marger_array);
```

Output: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uASvj))

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (6) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["m_name_e"]=>
    string(8) "Titus C."
    ["member_id"]=>
    string(10) "KZI37M3025"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["m_number"]=>
    int(9489455057)
    ["familyid"]=>
    string(10) "KZI54F2256"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["m_name_e"]=>
    string(10) "Baby Helen"
    ["member_id"]=>
    string(10) "KZI45M6402"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(6) "Female"
    ["m_number"]=>
    NULL
    ["familyid"]=>
    string(10) "KZI54F2256"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["m_name_e"]=>
    string(22) "Satheesh Premananth T."
    ["member_id"]=>
    string(10) "KZI69M3438"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["m_number"]=>
    NULL
    ["familyid"]=>
    string(10) "KZI69F5619"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["do_birth"]=>
    string(10) "1937-09-18"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["do_birth"]=>
    string(10) "1945-02-06"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["do_birth"]=>
    string(10) "1968-04-12"
  }
  [6]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["do_baptism"]=>
    string(10) "1969-04-13"
  }
  [7]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["do_confirm"]=>
    string(10) "1954-04-07"
  }
  [8]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (2) {
    ["mem_tbl_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["do_confirm"]=>
    string(10) "1990-04-29"
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is quite obviously incorrect and untested and unexplained.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't make it easy to merge objects like it does with arrays.

Ideally, you should be writing a more sophisticated query in your model to allow your database to merge this data.

In the absense of table schema details, you can manually set the result array with the first array, then iterate over the other arrays and write their data to the result array based on the first level key (or the `mem_tbl_id` if you wish).

Because the first array will contain all possible ids, the `isset()` check is not actually needed, but I'll added it for the sake of future readers (just uncomment if new identifiers might be encountered).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6bOkc))

```
$result = $array1;
foreach ([$array2, $array3, $array4] as $objectArray) {
    foreach ($objectArray as $id => $obj) {
        foreach ($obj as $prop => $val) {
            //if (!isset($result[$id])) {
            //    $result[$id] = (object) [];
            //} else {
                $result[$id]->$prop = $val;
            //}
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

For anyone who wishes to merge based on a shared column value (object property), then you can push reference variables representing each unique object id into the result array ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CtOFm))

```
$result = [];
foreach ([$array1, $array2, $array3, $array4] as $objectArray) {
    foreach ($objectArray as $obj) {
        if (!isset($ref[$obj->mem_tbl_id])) {
            $ref[$obj->mem_tbl_id] = $obj;
            $result[] = $ref[$obj->mem_tbl_id];
        } else {
            foreach ($obj as $prop => $val) {
                $ref[$obj->mem_tbl_id]->$prop = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```